# Hive Reading only one json row

Tags: json, hive, hiveql, create-table, hiveddl

I have a json like this

```
[{"event": "1", "meta": {"name":"Kumar","":"28"}}, {"event": "2", "meta": {"name":"Harsh","":"27"}}]
```

I removed the square bracket as in hive it is giving error
`org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected`

```
{"event": "1", "meta": {"name":"Kumar","":"28"}}, {"event": "2", "meta": {"name":"Harsh","":"27"}}
```

I am creating my table like this

```
create external table record_two(event string,meta struct<name:string,age:string>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/test/event_two/';
```

The table is created but when i run select it is only returning one record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records should be in separate lines in data file.

```
{"event": "1", "meta": {"name":"Kumar","age":"28"}}
{"event": "2", "meta": {"name":"Harsh","age":"27"}}
```

And no commas between records, only newline.

Comment: Its like thi only from sourec is ther any way to read it for single line or wirh extra braces

Comment: @KumarHarsh- put original array, define table as `complex_col array<struct<event:string,meta:struct<name:string,age:string>>>`, use ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'  See examples here:  https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde But in this case array will not be exploded. Serde can not produce more rows than it is in the file....